# Where is the button to 'Create Landscape Variation' in the Design View in Android Studio version 2021.2.1?

Tags: android, layout

For the new version 2021.2.1, I can't find the button for “create landscape variation” in the design view unlike the older one as following link:

The older one

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhZvB.jpg

what shows on the list of the New version

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Eelc.png

Thanks for your answer~

Answer (score 7):

Click on the drop-down labeled `activity_main.xml`

[image: activity main layout]

In the drop-down menu, you will find an option to `Create Landscape Qualifier`

[image: layout drop-down menu]

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct, and in case the button goes missing again, you can try the longer method.

1. go to: res -> layout -> New -> layout resource file.
   [Android Studio Dolphin (2021.3.1 patch 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob2hv.png)
2. in the dialogue box, enter the file name (same as the name of  portrait layout file.)
3. select orientation from available qualifiers list, and click on "**>>**" button. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBZ6i.png)
4. Select screen orientation and hit ok.
   [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6vcI.png)